# What is the probability that having $n$ random numbers (each maximum $n$-bit - numbers can be repeated) there is a sum of up to $2^n$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability that having $n$ random numbers (each maximum $n$-bit - numbers can be repeated) there is a sum of up to $2^n$ (the sum of any number of numbers - minimum one number, maximum $n$ numbers)?

Comment: Do you want a sum of exactly $2^n$ or a sum less than or equal to $2^n$?  What is the largest number that $n$ bits can represent?

Comment: I looking exactly $2^n$. Maximum $n$-bits number is $2^n-1$ (minimum is $0$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  You can use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) to find the number of ordered ways to express $2^n$ as a sum of $k$ terms.  How many ordered choices of $n$ numbers are there?  Take the ratio.